# Couchbase: Synchronizing views with a bucket

Tags: nosql, couchdb, couchbase

I've got a question for you couchbase pros: Is it possible to synchronize a subset of documents (eg. the documents within a view) with an other bucket?

So that the other bucket documents are always a direct subset of the "master" bucket?
if so, isn't that to much expensive in terms of perfomance? or does couchbase have any functionality to only create deeplinks to the documents instead of copying it?

Alternatively: is it possible to write views on views?

Thank you in advance!

--- EDIT ----

Let's say I want to have two sets (buckets) of documents S1 and S2. S2 is a subset of S1. Each set contains the same views V1, V2 and V3 since I want to be able to query any of them with the same logic/interface. In my case set S2 is build per user/company/store/whatever, in production there should be like 1000ish subsets S2 - to stay abstract let's call them S2a S2b and S2c.

The selection of documents which to be contained in any subset is done by a filtering instance (for example a view). Let's call these filtering instances F1 for filtering S1 to S2 hence F1a, F1b and F1c.

So with my actual knowledge of couchbase this results in the following design/view architecture: I've got the three "base" views to display V1,V2 and V3, and to realize S2a, S2b and S2c I must create the design views S2aV1, S2aV2, S2aV3, S2bV1, S2bV2, etc. (9 Views).

One could say "Well choose your keys wisely and you can avoid the sub views" but in my opinion this isn't that easy because of the following circumstances: In worst case the filter parameters change every minute and contain many WHERE IN constraints which could (at my actual point of view) not be handled efficiently querying k/v lists.

This leads to the following thoughts and the question I initially asked. If I use the same views in any subset (defined by a filter) shouldn't it be possible to build up an entity which helps me handling complex filtering? For example a function which is called during runtime while generating the view output? This could look like /design/view?filter=F1 or something like that.

Or do you have any other ideas to solve this problem? Or should I use SQL since it's more capable of handling frequently changing filters?

Comment: Could you add to the question a bit about the dev environment?  Java/C#/PHP, etc.?  That will likely factor into the answer.

Comment: Since the environment/client language doesn't affect how couchbase works i don't think this is important. But, if you need this information to answer the question just feel free to choose the environment of your choice. I'm happy for any suggestions.

Comment: It sort of does if you need to do some portion of this externally (which is why I asked), but the discussion has been clarified in the answer from scalabl3, so we'll see where we end up.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking for most models you don't really need to have bucket "subsets", is there a particular reason you are trying to do this and why you would want that data broken out? You can also query your views, or instead of a view on a view, you can just make a separate view that maps/filters further based on your needs (i.e. does the same job as a view on a view).

Comment: Yes, i also think that some well designed design documents should make any subsets unnecessary. But in my actual usecase i have to filter documents for many attributes like attr1 > 10, attr2 <= 20, attr3 = 30, attr4 between 1 and 2 order by attr5, attr4 etc.. so i thought it should be helpfull building a bucket subset with predefined filters to minimize the amount of existing documents, build some commonly used/filtered key/value pairs and filter the rest at application side.

Comment: I think your logic is sound. I think your concept of bucket subset, is, well what a view **is**. You mentioned the deeplinks in your comment with @JChris.  You can do referential links, but they are not followed by Couchbase itself, but you can follow them client side. I am not sure bucket copy is needed for what you're trying to accomplish. Am I understanding correctly: You want to be able to constantly have a subset of documents that match certain characteristics based on the json k/v's reduce the dataset on the bucket based on these for additonal m/r?

Comment: Another method of doing this subfilter would be with a compound view key where the first element (in the array) is the subset you're grouping on.  The functional result is pretty much the same from a view request perspective, and then no need to subset things.  For good reading in the general area, check out Bradley Holt's presentation from CouchConf Boston.  Not right on, but may trigger a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, i will check the presentation! I posted a clearer description and my response to scalabl3's question in the couchbase forums: http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/synchronizing-views-bucket#comment-1006731 so you're very welcome to comment on this.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on Elastic Search integration. Maybe better for your use case

Comment: If that is really you, J Chris, and not an imposter,  ;) could you add a little more detail to your answer, along with a link to extensive info?  (I gave you +1, since it's useful info as is, and since there's practically nothing you can do with only 1 rep point, but more discursive answers are generally preferred here.) Thanks for answering, and for all your awesome work on CouchDB & Couchbase!

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is write a view on your original bucket, and then copy the key/values from that view, to be documents in a new bucket.

It shouldn't be hard to write an automated framework for managing this so that you can keep the derived data up to date in near real time.

Comment: Yes, that's what i also thought about today. The thing is i don't know how much perfomance loss this approach means. Lets say you have a bucket containing 5 million documents, beeing CRUDed for a massive amount per second. Copying all changes made to these documents into another bucked also results in a massive design/view/map/reduce in the other bucket. IMHO the best way should be to write an addon for couchbase which allows something like deep links to existing documents in another bucket. What do you think?

Comment: We avoid deep links because on a cluster, there are no all ACID guarantees that span a single document. So it would be impossible, for instance, to create a record, and add a link to it from another record, all in a single transaction. For this reason, all links between documents must be "soft" and are therefore better off handled by application code.